# Fisher's exact test with altered null hypothesis/expected frequencies

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I'm trying to determine whether or not exposure to extreme temperatures after hospital discharge affects the chance that a surgical patient will be readmitted. An extreme heat exposure is defined as a post-discharge day during which the temperature in that patient's zip code was above the 95th percentile for that zip code's seasonal temperatures. This day must fall within 30 days after discharge or (if the patient was readmitted) before the readmission occurred. The average time to readmission is 11 days.

I'd been imagining that I could run a Fisher's exact test* on the contingency table produced from this, but I've realized that how I'm identifying extreme temperature exposures is biasing the groups: patients who are readmitted are LESS likely to be exposed to an extreme heat event because they have fewer days on which they might be exposed than a patient who isn't readmitted. This means that, even if there were no relationship between extreme heat and readmissions, we would expect approximately 3X as many extreme heat events in the never-readmitted group.

I've thought of accounting for this by dividing the number of readmissions in each group by the number of post-discharge days, but I don't like that metric because it's not easy to interpret. Ideally, I want to perform a Fisher's exact test where the null hypothesis is that the readmissions are distributed unevenly between the exposed and un-exposed groups (ie, I want to alter the expected frequencies to reflect this). Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show the table of counts on which you plan to do Fisher's Exact test? And explain explicitly what misgivings you have about using this test?

Comment: The problem is that I want to alter the expected frequencies

Comment: (pressed enter early)- I apologize if my explanation above wasn't clear enough-- the root of the problem is that I need to run a Fisher exact test with altered expected frequencies. I can do this with the Chi square test  (using https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) but in some cases, my counts are too low for Chi square to be valid, so I've been  trying to find a way to alter the expected frequencies for Fisher's Exact Test (which doesn't seem to be an option for Fisher in Scipy's implementation). Is it possible to alter expected freqs with Fisher?

Comment: Does scripy do simulated P-value for cases where expected counts are too small? // What you're trying to do seems strange/wrong/illegal to me, but I could be missing something. Maybe think through your goals again (and try to edit Q to explain clearly) and see if there's a better way.